# Add specific list modified files with git add

Tags: git, unix

I want to add only modified files.
I tried:

```
 git status | grep "modified" | cut -d " " -f4 | git add
```

or

```
git status | grep "modified" | cut -d " " -f4 | xargs git add
```

but it doesn't work.  What should I use?

Answer (score 2):

The first won't work because you don't use `xargs`.  The second doesn't work because the `cut` doesn't work — look at the output.

There's the command `git ls-files --modified` which gives you a list of modified files, one per line.  If you don't have spaces in your file names, simply use:

```
git ls-files --modified | xargs git add
```

If you have spaces in your file names, use the `-z` and `-0` options (making sure your variant of `xargs` supports `-0` as an option; it isn't universal, but is standard with GNU `xargs`):

```
git ls-files --modified -z | xargs -0 git add
```

While using `git status` with no flags, you need to be confident there are no spaces in your file names, and you could then use:

```
git status | awk '/[[:space:]]modified:[[:space:]]/{print $2}' | xargs git add
```

Also, `git status -s` gives a better, more easily parsed, output format.  You might use:

```
git status -s | sed -n '/^ M / s///p' | xargs git add
```

This works for the simple case (you've modified the file locally, it isn't yet in the index, and that's the only relevant change).  You should read the spiel from `git status --help` on the short format to work out how you need to handle the (many) other cases.

Also note that `git commit -a` will commit all modified files.

---

> I try: `git ls-files -o | grep "tests/" | xargs -0 git add`, but I get `xargs: argument line too long`.

The `-0` option to `xargs` requires 'lines' ending with null bytes.  Your `git` command doesn't generate those because you omitted the `-z` option.  You probably omitted that because you're worried about the `grep` in the middle (which will only work with lines ending with newlines) but your command line has to be self-consistent from end to end, either working with newlines or with nulls as the file name delimiters.  Fortunately, `grep` has an option `--null` (works on GNU and BSD `grep`; GNU also allows `-z`, but that means something different on BSD) to work with such data.  Therefore, you should be attempting either:

```
git ls-files -o -z | grep --null "tests/" | xargs -0 git add
```

or, if you don't have to worry about spaces in file names:

```
git ls-files -o | grep "tests/" | xargs git add
```

Comment: I try: git ls-files -o | grep "tests/" | xargs -0 git add . But I get xargs: argument line too long
@Jonathan Leffler

Comment: I want add only untracked files. I also try to use with z flag but it doesn't work @Jonathan Leffler

Comment: I apologize but it still doesn't work.  I get fatal pathspec. @Jonathan Leffer

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `git add -u`. [It will stage only modified files](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#git-add--u).

Comment: git add on directory also update stage of deleted files in directory ? @1615903